# Why can NSString not take ownership of memory allocated with new?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, dynamic-allocation, calloc

The static analyzer in Xcode 8 (beta 1) is warning me that `NSString`'s `initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:` can't take ownership of memory allocated by `new[]`. Is this an error? If not, why is this the case?

If I change my allocation to use `calloc` instead of `new[]`, the warning goes away.

Comment: I guess NSString and C++ don't mix very well.

Comment: @user3386109 Post this as an answer.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Ok, I converted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation says this about the `freeWhenDone` parameter:

> If YES, the receiver releases the memory with free() when it no longer
>   needs the data; if NO it won’t.

So `freeWhenDone` literally calls `free()` when done. To work with `new[]`, it would have to `delete[]` when done. Hence, the warning message is correct. If you don't want to copy the bytes, then you'll need to set `freeWhenDone` to `NO`, and `delete[]` the bytes when no longer needed.